# Nginx try_files directive works weird

Tags: nginx

spent several hours trying to figure out what problem is, but coudlnt.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

When users asks for js file, I want to check if there uglified copy exists in shared memory and serve it if it does. If there is no uglified copy, I would like to serve regular file.

Here is what I have in location:

```
location ~/require/[a-z0-9]+/(.*) {
   try_files /dev/shm/uglified/$1 /public/javascripts/$1;
}
```

AS you can see, if user asks for a file `/require/fe45be18b99f9099efbc98a71f67924aef72d58a/app/require-config.js`

1. We should check if file `/dev/shm/uglified/app/require-config.js` exist and serve it if it does.
2. Serve file `app/require-config.js` from `/public/javascripts/` location if it's not served in 1.

Well, it looks simple, but doesnt work.
All files exist - in `dev/shm` and `public` locations.

But:

1. File from `dev/shm` folder is never served, no matter if this location first ot second in try_files directive.
2. File from `public` location served only and if it is on second place in try_files directive.

e.g. `try_files /dev/shm/uglified/$1 /public/javascripts/$1;` works

`try_files /public/javascripts/$1 /dev/shm/uglified/$1;` doesnt work, although I just change places of locations in directive.

Could anyone advise why files from /dev/shm never picked up and why order of locations in try_files directive matter?

Comment: `try_files` requires URIs as parameters, not pathnames. The pathname is constructed from the document root (specified by the `root` directive). Maybe you can map or symlink your shared memory into the document root.

Comment: Thanks!, you comment was helpfull for finding solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Richard Smith comment, I fugured out how to make it work:

```
#that's the basic location, where we just redirect request to /dev/shm/ location
location ~/require/[a-z0-9]+/(.*) {
    echo_location /dev/shm/uglified/$1;
}

#that's location to serve files from shared memory
location ~ ^/dev/shm/uglified/(.*) {

    #set the root
    root /dev/shm/uglified/;

    #try file in this file, if it does not exist, redirect to public location
    try_files /$1 /public/javascripts/$1;

}
```